export GPG_TTY=$(tty) is added to zsh profile automatically on terminal init
On my laptop, I've realized that everytime I start-up my iTerm2 terminal (on OS X) -- export GPG_TTY=$(tty) is automatically appended to my ~/.zshrc file. I also do not have a GPG agent installed on my machine.
I've commented out my entire ~/.zshrc file, and still have that line appended everytime I load up my terminal. I've also used a different terminal app and have experienced the same.
Does anyone have any tips on how to triage this weird bug?

Check ~/.zprofile
